# Merging Two Columns in DataFrame With Variable Column Names

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Editing my original post to hopefully simplify my question... I'm merging multiple DataFrames into one, SomeData.DataFrame, which gives me the following:

```
     Key     2019-02-17    2019-02-24_x    2019-02-24_y    2019-03-03
0    A        80           NaN             NaN              80                         
1    B        NaN          NaN             45               36         
2    C        44           NaN             39              NaN            
3    D        80           NaN             NaN              12                         
4    E        49            2              NaN             NaN
```

What I'm trying to do now is efficiently merge the columns ending in "_x" and "_y" while keeping everything else in place so that I get:

```
     Key     2019-02-17    2019-02-24     2019-03-03
0    A        80           NaN             80                         
1    B        NaN          45              36         
2    C        44           39              NaN            
3    D        80           NaN             12                         
4    E        49            2              NaN
```

The other issue I'm trying to account for is that the data contained in SomeData.DataFrame changes weekly so that my column headers are unpredictable. Meaning, some weeks I may not have the above issue at all and other weeks, there may be multiple instances for example:

```
     Key  2019-02-17  2019-02-24_x  2019-02-24_y  2019-03_10_x  2019-03-10_y  
  0   A       80           NaN          NaN           80          NaN   
  1   B       NaN          NaN           45           36          NaN              
  2   C       44           NaN           39          NaN           12   
  3   D       80           NaN          NaN           12          NaN                
  4   E       49            2           NaN          NaN           17
```

So that again the desired result would be:

```
     Key  2019-02-17  2019-02-24   2019-03_10   
  0   A       80           NaN          80            
  1   B       NaN          45           36                       
  2   C       44           39           12   
  3   D       80           NaN          12                          
  4   E       49            2           17
```

Is what I'm asking reasonable or am I venturing outside the bounds of Pandas' limits? I can't find anyone trying to do anything similar so I'm not sure anymore. Thank you in advance!

Comment: I think you have a typo in your second dataframe.   "2019-03_10_x" should be "2019-03-10_x"

Answer (score 0):

Edited answer to updated question:

```
df = df.set_index('Key')
df.groupby(df.columns.str.split('_').str[0], axis=1).sum()
```

Output:

```
         2019-02-17  2019-02-24  2019-03-03
    Key                                    
    A          80.0         0.0        80.0
    B           0.0        45.0        36.0
    C          44.0        39.0         0.0
    D          80.0         0.0        12.0
    E          49.0         2.0         0.0

Second dataframe Output:

df.groupby(df.columns.str.split('_').str[0], axis=1).sum()

Output:

     2019-02-17  2019-02-24  2019-03-10
Key                                    
A          80.0         0.0        80.0
B           0.0        45.0        36.0
C          44.0        39.0        12.0
D          80.0         0.0        12.0
E          49.0         2.0        17.0
```

---

```
You could try something like this:

    df_t = df.T
    df_t.set_index(df_t.groupby(level=0).cumcount(), append=True)\
        .unstack().T\

    .sort_values(df.columns[0])[df.columns.unique()]\
    .reset_index(drop=True)
```

Output:

```
  val03-20 03-20 val03-24 03-24
0        a     1        d     5
1        b     6        e     7
2        c     4        f    10
3      NaN   NaN        g     5
4      NaN   NaN        h     6
5      NaN   NaN        i     1
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I couldn't quite get it to work for me unfortunately. I'm revising my question another way.